# Print output from org code block immediately

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have an org mode file I use to run some moderately long analyses. Evaluating individual blocks may take 15 minutes to an hour or so. I usually wrap longer bits with calls to `date`, so I can later review how long those parts took. e.g:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results output
  echo Starting transfer ...
  date
  ## rsync 30 GB directory
  echo Finished transfer!
  date

  echo Starting analysis ...
  date
  ## long-running analysis
  echo Analysis finished!
  date
#+END_SRC
```

This works fine, but after it starts I can't see when each step started and stopped until the entire process is complete.

Is there a way to get org to print the results as they are generated, rather than all at once when the code block is done? i.e., as soon as my transfer is finished I see the "Finished transfer!" message with the output from `date`, while the script continues on to the next section.

What I'd like is a way to monitor the progress of these computations. I don't want to put each line in its own source code block, as I want the entire process to continue without my having to submit each command explicitly.

Comment: One problem is that `org-babel-execute` is synchronous. So it can't give the results before it has executed the full block. There is [`ob-async.el`](https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async). Pityingly that does also not solve the problem since the block is sent to the asynchronous emacs as a whole and [interprocess communication is not possible](https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async/issues/33#issuecomment-399449442).  There exists already a [similar request](https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async/issues/13) for `ob-async`.

Comment: Some time ago I've written up `org-babel-execute:eshell-script` which sends the code block contents to Eshell. An Eshell session works asynchronously with `start-process`. So it would be possible in principle to queue the 
Eshell commands and let eshell do its job asynchronously. The progress would be visible in the eshell session. Triggering the code block output after the eshell script has finished could probably be stolen from `ob-async`. There comes my question: Is it thinkable to switch from Bash to Eshell?